# Click on the chart to zoom chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know highstock not support click to zoom graph 
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/zooming
But I want to click on the graph, the graph will display all screens, including the form "Time updates". How can i do?
For example: http://jsfiddle.net/DuyThoLe/58bzo3vg/17/`enter code here`

Comment: What you mean by all screens? Could you attach a mockups how it should be printed?

Comment: I mean if I have four graphs to size is 660: 283, I want when I click on any graph, the graph will see it on full screen. But then I can not click on the points on the graph and printf chart. Example for static graph http://jsfiddle.net/DuyThoLe/o4hhgop9/1/ and i do it for dynamic graph http://jsfiddle.net/DuyThoLe/o4hhgop9/5/

Comment: You can use a highslide to do this. Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/y4JV5/4/ / http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/GqhEX/

Comment: I did it, but it can not click on the point on the graph, the graph does not print, I want to form "Time update" also zoom the graph when clicking (can adjust the time when zooming in form "Time update").http://jsfiddle.net/DuyThoLe/6jLg8fg5/2/

Comment: Like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/6jLg8fg5/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from this Hgihcharts demo - http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-container/

... it is possible to get it to work with your chart: http://jsfiddle.net/6jLg8fg5/1/

Later you wanted to include "Time update" in pop up window, so it is added to div that will change its class (and because of CSS will be displayed on top, like a pop up): http://jsfiddle.net/6jLg8fg5/4/

Next you wanted to be able to prin, export, click legend without popping up or back down the chart. You could postpone (e.g. using `setTimeout`) pop up effect and check if click is not triggering legend or exporting menu.
Series have `legendItemClick` event - so first we shuold check that. While printing chart will have afterPrinting and beforePrinting events triggered. For exporting - it is possible to rewrite `getChartHTML` from exporting module using wrapping (extending Highcharts) - http://jsfiddle.net/6jLg8fg5/5/

JS:

```
$(function () {
    (function (H) {
        H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getChartHTML', function (proceed) {
            printing = true;
            // Run original proceed method
            return this.container.innerHTML;
        });
    }(Highcharts));

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var legendClicked = false,
        printing = false; //or exporting
    // Create the chart
    $('#chart1').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            height: 283,
            width: 660,
            events: {
                beforePrint: function() {
                    printing = true;
                },
                afterPrint: function(){
                    printing = false;
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: true
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: [{
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    legendClicked = true;
                }
            },
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)]);
                }
                return data;
            }())

        }]

    });

    //the form action
    var updateInterval = 10000;
    $("#updateInterval").val(updateInterval).change(function () {

        var v = $(this).val();
        if (v && !isNaN(+v)) {
            updateInterval = +v;
            if (updateInterval < 1) {
                updateInterval = 1;
            } else if (updateInterval > 50000) {
                updateInterval = 10000;
            }
            $(this).val("" + updateInterval);
        }
    });

    function update() {
        var series = $('#chart1').highcharts().series[0];
        x = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
    }

    update();



    $('.chart-container').bind('mousedown', function () {
        var source = this;
        if(!printing) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //check if legend was clicked
            if (legendClicked) {
                legendClicked = false;
            } else if ($('.highcharts-contextmenu').css('display') === 'block' || printing) {
                //check if context menu is visible
                printing = false;
            } else {
                //else do popup or back to default
                $('#chart-with-time-update').toggleClass('modal');
                $('.chart', source).highcharts().reflow();
            }
        }, 150);
        }
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.chart {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.modal .chart {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Finally you needed to make it work with multiple charts -  http://jsfiddle.net/6jLg8fg5/13/

(This problem was also discussed on Highcharts forum: http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/click-on-the-chart-to-zoom-chart-t33714/)